# How to rearrange a nested list grouping by a variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I imagine this is very easy but I can't figure it out. Please help me!

I have data from a .csv file with this structure. It has 157 specimens and 21 X and Y coordinates for each one, so in total 3297 rows with 3 columns (specimen, x, y).

| Specimen | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| specimen 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| specimen 1 | 1.3 | 1.4 |
| specimen 1 | 1.5 | 1.6 |
| specimen 2 | 0.7 | 0.8 |
| specimen 2 | 0.9 | 1.0 |
| specimen 2 | 1.1 | 1.2 |

But I need it to look like this:

| Specimen | X1 | Y1 | X2 | Y2 | X3 | Y3 | ... | X21 | Y21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| specimen 1 | 1.1 | 1.3 | 1.3 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | ... | ... | ... |
| specimen 2 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 1.0 | 1.1 | 1.2 | ... | ... | ... |

I tried in R doing this:

```
mydata <- read.csv("measurements.csv") # read file
mydata_coord <- data.frame(mydata$Specimen, mydata$X, mydata$Y) # Create dataframe with specimen and coordinates
mydata_nested <- mydata %>% nest_by(mydata.Specimen)
```

But this creates a nested list that looks like this:

[image: Nested table I get in R]

How do I make that nested list become a dataframe with pairs of x,y in the same row for each specimen with names x1,y1,x2,y2,...x21,y21? The result would then be a dataframe of 42 columns and 157 rows.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) Try searching here on Stackoverflow for `[r] reshape long to wide` and you should get many results for this issue. 2) `mydata_coord <- data.frame(mydata$Specimen, mydata$X, mydata$Y)` will break your names, instead try `mydata_coord <- mydata[c("Specimen","X","Y")]` 3) Consider whether you can work with your data in the long/'tidy' format without reshaping it, as that is fairly standard practice and a pretty efficient way to store the data you have - see http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html

Comment: `library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
df %>%
  group_by(Specimen) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "id", values_from = c("X", "Y"), names_sep = "")`

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you so much! It worked great so I can finally move on with my analysis. I'm glad people like you exist : )

Comment: @GregorThomas I just realized that it's great but it gives me the values x1,x2,x3..x21, y1,y2,y3,...,y21 instead of x1,y1,x2,y2,...x21,y21. Yikessss...

Comment: You can reorder the columns---call the previous result `df_wide`, then `nm = names(df_wide)[-1];
nm_ordered = nm[order(as.integer(substr(nm, 2, 20)))];
df_wide = df_wide[c("Specimen", nm_ordered)]`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you thank you thank you! It's one of those moments when you have a deadline and can't take the time to study the whole thing to figure it out!